# jq - How to get an alternative key if null

Tags: json, bash, jq

given the following json -

```
[
  {
    "mail": "user1@example.com",
    "userPrincipalName": "user1@example.com"
  },
  {
    "mail": "user2@example.com",
    "userPrincipalName": "user2@example.org"
  },
  {
    "mail": "null",
    "userPrincipalName": "user3@example.com"
  }
]
```

I want to get

```
user1@example.com
user2@example.com
user3@example.com
```

I want to get all of the .com addresses. So I'm trying to write an if/then to check for mail being null. and if so get userPrincipleName instead.

Edit -

Apologies - I forgot to add, I'm running this in a bash script

`cat $JSON | jq -r '.[].mail // .[].userPrincipalName'`

Comment: for `user1` and `user2`, `mail` is not null, so it should been the one with `@` in your expected output?

Comment: @Inian You're right, I've fixed

Comment: that's what I'm trying to figure out, I want to check for that null and get userPrincipalName instead

Comment: @Michael you want to achieve this using ```jq``` command. yes?

Comment: @dropyourcoffee yes please

Comment: yup. just added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`jq '.[]|if .mail | contains("null") then .userPrincipalName else .mail end' $JSON`

Edition:

`jq '.[]|if (.mail == null or .mail == "null") then .userPrincipalName else .mail end' $JSON`

Comment: that works - thank you - for completeness (and I might run in to it later) how would this be different if it was an actual null and not a string?

Comment: Do you  mean actual null by 
1) key-value pair doesn't exist at all; OR 2) something like null instead of "null"?

Comment: in case of 2, the file is not json file any more then, so you cannot process it with ```jq```

Comment: an actual null as in "mail": null

Comment: Correction. you still CAN process without quotations ```""```.
As @ Eldar suggested you can replace ```if .mail | contains("null")``` with ```if (.mail == null or .mail == "null")```

Comment: short answer, 
```jq '.[]|if (.mail == null or .mail == "null") then .userPrincipalName else .mail end' $JSON```

Answer (score 5):

```
 cat $JSON | jq -r 'map(if (.mail == null or .mail == "null")  then .userPrincipalName else .mail end)'
```

Since you asked it for bash jq method remains the same. we map the values of array check if `mail == "null"` if true use other property else use itself.

Here is the [jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/DpmOFS9cTNn) link

Comment: awesome @Eldar.

Comment: See [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something as mentioned below:

```
var newArray = [];
arr.forEach((obj) => {
    if (obj.mail !== 'null') {
        newArray.push(obj.mail);
    } else {
        newArray.push(obj.userPrincipalName);
    }});
console.log(newArray);   // ["user1.example.com","user2.example.com","user3.example.com"]
```